# How to use importlib for rewriting bytecode?

Tags: python, import, bytecode-manipulation

I'm looking for a way to use [importlib](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/importlib) in Python 2.x to rewrite bytecode of imported modules on-the-fly. In other words, I need to hook my own function between the compilation and  execution step during import. Besides that I want the import function to work just as the built-in one.

I've already did that with *imputil*, but that library doesn't cover all cases and is deprecated anyway.

Comment: "I need to hook my own function between the compilation and execution step"  Isn't this what decorators are for?  Are you monkey patching?  What is the point of this?

Comment: I am sure that, given that Michał has already implemented it in imputil, he has a point for it.

Comment: I'm an author of Pythoscope, a unit test generator. In order to intercept events of a running application I need to do some bytecode manipulation first. You can see my implementation of this using imputil here: http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~pythoscope-developers/pythoscope/trunk/annotate/head:/bytecode_tracer/code_rewriting_importer.py That fails in some cases (e.g. it doesn't work when pickling is involved), so I need a more bulletproof solution. importlib AFAIK is regarded as the new standard for import hooks, but I don't know much about it, thus my question.

Answer (score 2):

Having had a look through the `importlib` source code, I believe you could subclass `PyLoader` in the `_bootstrap` module and override `get_code`:

```
class PyLoader:
    ...

    def get_code(self, fullname):
    """Get a code object from source."""
    source_path = self.source_path(fullname)
    if source_path is None:
        message = "a source path must exist to load {0}".format(fullname)
        raise ImportError(message)
    source = self.get_data(source_path)
    # Convert to universal newlines.
    line_endings = b'\n'
    for index, c in enumerate(source):
        if c == ord(b'\n'):
            break
        elif c == ord(b'\r'):
            line_endings = b'\r'
            try:
                if source[index+1] == ord(b'\n'):
                    line_endings += b'\n'
            except IndexError:
                pass
            break
    if line_endings != b'\n':
        source = source.replace(line_endings, b'\n')

    # modified here
    code = compile(source, source_path, 'exec', dont_inherit=True)
    return rewrite_code(code)
```

I assume you know what you're doing, but on behalf of programmers everywhere I believe I should say: ***ugh*** =p

Comment: Yes, I know what I'm doing, thanks. ;) Anyway, only now I've noticed that the importlib backport only backports a single function, not the whole library. Ehh, back to square one...